# Spring Security : LockedException is thrown instead of BadCredentialsException, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

> Using Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE

For basic user authentication using spring-security framework, I implemented spring-security `DaoAuthenticationProvider`

When user tries to login with correct username, **incorrect** password and user's **account is already locked**, then i expected that spring-security authentication module would be throwing `BadCredentialsException` But instead it throws `LockedException`

My Questions are

1. why spring-security is processing the user for further authentication while the credentials specially password is incorrect ?
2. Is it good practice to show message in application that "User is Locked" even if the password for the user is invalid ?
3. How do i manage to generate/catch `BadCredentialsException` for invalid password and locked user ?

Any help would be appreciated. Authentication Provider implementation code is

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class LoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    @Override
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            Authentication auth = super.authenticate(authentication);
            // if reach here, means login success, else exception will be thrown

            // reset the user attempts
            userDAO.resetPasswordRetryAttempts(authentication.getName());

            return auth;
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            // invalid login, update user attempts
            userDAO.updatePasswordRetryAttempts(authentication.getName(), PropertyUtils.getLoginAttemptsLimit());
            throw ex;
        } catch (LockedException ex) {
            // this user is locked
            throw ex;
        } catch (AccountExpiredException ex) {
            // this user is expired
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You asked:

> Spring Security : LockedException is thrown instead of BadCredentialsException, why?

It is because spring security will first check that the account exist and is valid, and after that it checks the password.

More concrete: it is done in `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate`. In an **very brief** description the method works this way:

```
user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
...
preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
...
postAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
```

- `retrieveUser` - load the user
- `preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);` - `DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks`: check for locked...
- `additionalAuthenticationChecks` - checks the password
- `postAuthenticationChecks.check(user);` - `DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks` check for not expired credentials

The good point is, that `preAuthenticationChecks` and `postAuthenticationChecks` are references to the Interface `UserDetailsChecker` so you can change them. Just implement your own two `UserDetailsChecker`, the one Null-Implementation for pre, and one for post that checks everything:

- `!user.isAccountNonLocked()`
- `!user.isEnabled()`
- `!user.isAccountNonExpired()`
- `!user.isCredentialsNonExpired()`

Comment: Well that was something i didn't know about spring-security. Just one more thing, in practical situation would that be alright if we tell the user that the account is locked, even with wrong password, who is trying to authenticate ???

Comment: @Waseem Akhtar: I am not in the position to justify your second question: "Is it good practice...", but IMHO you are right. -- Anyway the good thing of Spring (security) is, that you just need to have a look at the code to answer such question like yours, that is at least the way I did.

Comment: also check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56202422/1533783

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when there are more than one user with the same credential (name , email etc.) it the database. It was a test anyway. After I deleted those duplications everything's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tried in the way by implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` in your `User.class` and overridded the below methods, then please make sure you return true instead false. Because by deafult they coming with false which means we are telling that all the accounts are locked.

```
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "user_master")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {            
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {          
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```